# Prevent TextBlocks from being rendered on top of each other

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to add sometimes one, sometimes two different TextBlocks into a single grid field. It works fine if it's only one; if I add two, however, they are not written one below the other but are written over each other so I can't read any of them anymore.

Is there a possibility to maybe add a linebreak after the first TextBlock or do somthing else to avoid this behaviour?

My code to add the TextBlocks is:

```
 for (int k = 0; k < verschiedeneFaecher.Count(); k++){
     [...]
     var fachLehrer = new TextBlock { Text = fachString, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left };
     [...]
     Grid.SetColumn(fachLehrer, j + 1);
     Grid.SetRow(fachLehrer, i + 2);
     Stundenplan.Children.Add(fachLehrer);
 }
```

If there should be only one TextBlock, `verschiedeneFaecher.Count()` is 1, if there should be two, its 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a StackPanel to handle the multi-line nature of your requirement, and then adding the textbocks to the StackPanel .

XAML

```
<Grid Name="Stundenplan">
    <StackPanel Name="AddChildrenHere" />
    <!-- XAML for other controls -->
</grid>
```

Then...

```
 for (int k = 0; k < verschiedeneFaecher.Count(); k++){
     [...]
     var fachLehrer = new TextBlock { Text = fachString, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left };
     [...]
     AddChildrenHere.Children.Add(fachLehrer);
 }
```

The outer grid is not really required in this solution, but I left it in for the sake of clarity.  Also, your original code mentioned the variable `i` but didn't instantiate it so I ignored it.  You should have enough to go one here to work the exact placement out, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `Grid.RowDefinitions` collection of your `Stundenplan` grid to make sure that you define the correct number of rows in your grid or else all the items will appear on top of each other.

See [MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.rowdefinitions%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).